# How to convert List of Entite with List<Entite > to a treeSet

Tags: java, collections

Creating inernet shop, help please 
i have Category entity that has List in it, and i need to send this tree in json, but using dao it finds all categories and my json looks like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Phones & Accessories",
        "products": [],
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Mobile Phones",
                "products": [],
                "subcategories": []
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "Phone Bags & Cases",
                "products": [],
                "subcategories": []
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "title": "Mobile Phone Accessories",
                "products": [],
                "subcategories": []
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "title": "Mobile Phone Parts",
                "products": [],
                "subcategories": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Mobile Phones",
        "products": [],
        "subcategories": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Phone Bags & Cases",
        "products": [],
        "subcategories": []
    },
```

So the categories duplicate, as I understand I dont need to return a list but rather a treeSet in my controller method. But I don't understand how to do that, how to implement comparable method so my json get no duplicated entities
Controller mapping

```
@Controller
public class CategoryController {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @RequestMapping("/categories")
    public @ResponseBody TreeSet<Category> getCategoriesTree(){
        List<Category> list = categoryService.findAll();
        TreeSet<Category> categoryTree = new TreeSet<>(list);
        return categoryTree;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/categorieslist")
    public @ResponseBody List<Category> getCategoriesList(){
        List<Category> list = categoryService.findAll();
        TreeSet<Category> categorytree = new TreeSet<>(list);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Category  implements Comparable<Category> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "category_product", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") })
    private Set<Product> products;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE )
    @JoinTable(name = "category_subcategory", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "subcategory_id") })
    private List<Category> subcategories;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Category o) {
        if (o.getSubcategories().contains(this))  {
           return 0;
        } else return 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: treesets have nothing in common with your case - tree stands for underlying mechanism of storing elements sorted. but you mean some kind of tree structure, don't mess up this concepts

Comment: List<Category> list = categoryService.findAll();
        TreeSet<Category> categoryTree = new TreeSet<>(list);

Comment: @Override
    public int compareTo(Category o) {
       if (this.getSubcategories().contains(o)) return 0;
        else return 1;
    }

Answer (score 0):

the answer was more simple
I just filtered all the categories with empty list
and got 'Root' categories

```
List<Category> categories = categoryService.findAll();
    List<Category> roots = categories.stream().filter(category -> !category.getSubcategories().isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return roots;
```